# Increase the Query Parallelism Capacity on Cached RDD (DataFrame) with Spark-Job-Server on a Standalone Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, spark-jobserver

First of all, our standalone Spark cluster consists of 20 nodes, each one of them has 40 cores and 128G memory (including the 2 masters).

1.
We use Spark-Job-Server for reusing Spark-Context (in the core, we want to reuse cached RDD for querying), when we set the Spark executor memory to 33G each node and execute the SQL on the DataFrame such as "select * from tablename limit 10", then the result will be in mal-formatted UTF-8 style which cannot be resolved by app.

But if we set the executor-memory below 32G,the result is well formed then. We kept the rest setting untouched while we changed  the memory.

Can anyone knows Spark & Spark-Job-Server well tell us the cause of the messed code?
Is it the too much memory giving the reason why we get our result mess coded?

2.
The second thing is a more specific one in our user case.
We load 60G data into the mem and persist it using the memory-only storage level, the data is actually a structured table we will do some query on.
Then we tried the Spark SQL on our cached 60G RDD (registered as a DataFrame), specifically speaking, execute several queries like "select column from tableName where condition clause" in parallel, which lead to OOM exception.

We really want to increase our query parallelism with current cluster .
Can anyone give us some hints or some info which will help us solve our parallelism requirement.

Comment: The Spark version is 1.5.2. Thanks.

Comment: I also changed the RDD partition strategies, for example: fixed NO. 1400, 1000, 500 etc. But the parallelism is still there with no change.
Of cause the number of cores and volume of memory stands for the number of tasks a cluster can run simultaneously. 
But can anyone who experts on Spark and Spark-JobServer tell us how can we improve the parallelism on the software side? Thanks.

Comment: How is it going? Did you success?